# Find closest value to reference in matrix, columnwise

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an example matrix `A`

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5; 2 3 4 5 6; 3 4 5 6 7; 4 5 6 7 8]

A =

 1     2     3     4     5
 2     3     4     5     6
 3     4     5     6     7
 4     5     6     7     8
```

I want to find the closest value per row. 
So if `X = 3.4`

```
[MinDif,MinPos]=min(abs(A-X));

MinPos =

     3     2     1     1     1
```

Now I want to fill these positions in a second matrix B. So positions (3,1) (2,2) (1,3) (1,4) (1,5).

```
B = [10 11 12 13 14 ;11 12 13 14 15 ; 13 14 15 16 17; 14 15 16 17 18]

B =

    10    11    12    13    14
    11    12    13    14    15
    13    14    15    16    17
    14    15    16    17    18
```

I want my answer to be

```
ans =

    13 12 12 13 14
```

I tried

```
B(MinPos,find(MinPos))
```

But that doesn't give me what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`sub2ind`**](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
% given
A = [1 2 3 4 5; 2 3 4 5 6; 3 4 5 6 7; 4 5 6 7 8]
B = [10 11 12 13 14 ;11 12 13 14 15 ; 13 14 15 16 17; 14 15 16 17 18]
X = 3.4
[~, MinPos] = min(abs(A-X));

sz = size(A);                      % size of input
idx = sub2ind(sz,MinPos,1:sz(2));  % linear indices correlated with indices of minima
out = B(idx);                      % linear indexing of output
```

---

```
out =  13    12    12    13    14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ['linear'](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html#d120e791139) option to get linear indexes:

```
[MinDif,MinPos]=min(abs(A-X), [], 1, 'linear');
```

Get the corresponding elements in B:

```
B(MinPos)
```

Fill the elemets:

```
B(MinPps) = MinDif;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code

```
B((size(B,1)-1)*(1:length(MinPos)) + MinPos)
```

such that

```
ans =

   12   15   13   13   17
```